# React 16 Component does not render json data into component

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have a component called `projectDetailPage` where I am passing json variable  to render it's value. I have a container component called `ProjectCardContainer` which has anchor tag and  I am opening it to `projectDetailPage` I am attempting to render the json date and for that I am checking it with `console.log(json);`. When I click on `ProjectCardContainer`

```
<h6 className="link-hidden">
  <a href={`/projectdetailpage/${props.projectID}`} >
    {props.projectName}
  </a>
</h6>
```

It opens `projectDetailPage` and I don't see any `console.log`. What is going wrong here? Also is there any correct approach for rendering json in to the component? Thanks.

[Gist code Link](https://gist.github.com/amarg26/d37e183b507b93c32ddf3540ef4c996c)

Comment: Can you try to stringify the JSON with `JSON.stringify()`?

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify(json));` displays JSON in `ProjectCardContainer` but not in `ProjectDetailPage` component.

Comment: Can you post more code? Hard to see what's wrong with this with so little code.

Comment: did you check console if u r getting any undefined errors ?

Comment: There are no Undefined error in the console. I have already given entire code In Gist link to avoid showing too much code. There is `Card` component which has link on `ProjectDetailPage`. When user clicks on `Card` I wants to render its relevant data from `json` to React  component `ProjectDetailPage`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to Add the `<Route path='/ProjectDetailPage/:projectID' component={ProjectDetailPage} />` in my root component. I Added it and solves my problem.